# How do I reuse knobs in Storybook's Component Story Format (CSF)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, storybook

I've a simple `Button` component with multiple stories. All these stories need the same knobs configuration.

This approach works:

```js
export const Default = () => <Button size={select('size', ['x-large', 'normal', 'x-small'], 'x-small')}>Button</Button>;
export const Disabled = () => <Button disabled size={select('size', ['x-large', 'normal', 'x-small'], 'x-small')}>Button</Button>;
export const Outline = () => <Button outline size={select('size', ['x-large','normal', 'x-small'], 'x-small')}>Button</Button>;
```

However, I don't want to repeat the `select` statement over and over. I tried spreading, like so:

```js
const knobs = {
  size: select('size', ['x-large', 'normal', 'x-small'], 'x-small')
};
​
export const Default = () => <Button {...knobs}>Button</Button>;
export const Disabled = () => <Button disabled {...knobs}>Button</Button>;
export const Outline = () => <Button outline {...knobs}>Button</Button>;
```

But doesn't work: the knobs show in the UI, but when I update the dropdown, the new value isn't passed to the knob.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently this works when you spread the props as a function. This is how I eventually got things working:

```js
const knobs = () => ({
  size: select('size', ['x-large', 'normal', 'x-small'], 'x-small')
});
​
export const Default = () => <Button {...knobs()}>Button</Button>;
export const Disabled = () => <Button disabled {...knobs()}>Button</Button>;
export const Outline = () => <Button outline {...knobs()}>Button</Button>;
```

Comment: How strange. Thanks for this!

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this:

```
const knobs = {
  size: () => select('size', ['x-large', 'normal', 'x-small'], 'x-small')
};
```

Comment: Tried that one. When I use it, it shows the select in the UI but it doesn't work. See my answer, that's how I eventually got it to work.